# Wamp in LAN with a real domain name

Tags: wamp

I have domain name and I have set virtual host I want to know how to connect the domain name to my virtual host I'm new to this so plz answer easy understandable answers

http-vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost 
    ServerAlias localhost 
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www"> 
        Order Deny,Allow 
        Deny from all 
        Allow from localhost 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost example.com> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/example" 
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias example.com 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    <Directory C:/wamp/www> 
        Order Deny,Allow 
        Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to show the website using domain name internal and external

Comment: **1** Are you behind a router? **2** Have you port forwarded port 80 on your router?

Comment: Also show your Virtual Host definitions please, thats `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: http-vhosts.conf NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "C:/wamp/www">
  Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost example.com>   
 DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/example" 
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 <Directory C:/wamp/www>
  Order Deny,Allow   
  Allow from all 
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>want to show the website using domain name internal and external

Answer (score 1):

Ok so lets assume your domain is called `mysite.com` and you also need a testing version of the site, lets say `mysite.dev`

You have used Apache 2.2 syntax so I assume you are using a version of Apache that is 2.2.x, *however if you are using Apache 2.4.x see below for correct syntax*

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost 
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow 
        Deny from all 
        Allow from localhost 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

# This is for accessing a development version of the site
# note: only accessible from this machine
<VirtualHost *:80>                        <-- change
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite.test" 
    ServerName mysite.dev

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite.test"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks     <-- moved
        Order Deny,Allow 
        Deny from all 
        Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

#New Virtual Host for your real domain name
#accessible from the internet
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite.com" 
    ServerName mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite.com"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        Order Allow,Deny                  
        Allow from all 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

If you are using Apache 2.4.x then the syntax should be chabged like so :-

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80     <- not required in apache 2.4

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www" 
    ServerName localhost 
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www"> 
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost> 

# This is for accessing a development version of the site
# note: only accessible from this machine and stored in different folder
<VirtualHost *:80>                        <-- change
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite.test" 
    ServerName example.dev 

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite.test"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks     <-- moved
        Require local
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

#New Virtual Host for your real domain name
#accessible from the internet
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/mysite.com" 
    ServerName mysite.com 
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/mysite.com"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
        Require all granted
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to add the `mysite.dev` site to the windows HOSTS file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` but NOT the live domain name

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1  mysite.dev

::1  localhost
::1  mysite.dev
```